# Why Uddhava Gita starts differently - are there different Uddhava Gitas?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, gita

I found some texts on Uddhava Gita online:

1. [first](http://bhagavata.org/pdf/uddhavagita-eng.pdf)
2. [second](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/uddhavagiitaa.pdf)
3. [third](https://www.amazon.in/Uddhava-Gita-Krishnas-Final-Lessons-ebook/dp/B00CPG20LO/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=uddhava%20gita&qid=1595865329&sr=8-2#reader_B00CPG20LO) # this is amazon preview, but you can preview chapter 1
   sloka 1

They all start differently:

1. first start with *suka uwacha*
2. second starts with *badarayadi uwacha*
3. third starts with *shri bhagwan uwacha*

So, I'm a bit confused with which one is to be followed. Are these all different Uddhava Gitas?

P.S: Please tell me what this canto 11 chapter 6 to 29 means given in the first link.

Comment: "Please tell me what this canto 11 chapter 6 to 29 means given in the first link" -- Uddhaava Gita is not a seperate scripture..Actually, Chapter 6 to 29 of Bhagavata Purana: [Canto/Skandha 11](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/) are referred as uddhava Gita..

Comment: @YDS , you have any idea why these start differently?

Comment: What is a Canto?

Comment: there are different recensions of many shastras, including the Uddhava Gita.

Comment: Canto is word used by ISKCON for Sanskrit word Skandha...that is actually nothing but grouping of chapters...so u can think Canto as Section of a particular scripture..

Comment: Considering Srila Prabhupada's mother tongue Canto is probably derived from the Bengali কান্ড (Kaanda).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that Uddhaava Gita is not a separate scripture, it's actually part of **Bhagavata Purana: Canto/Section/Skandha 11**. Similarly, Bhagavat Gita is also not a separate scripture, it's actually part of **Mahabharata: Parva/Book 6** named Bhishma Parva.

But these Gitas mainly studied as separate scriptures. Historically, Bhagavat Gita got attention from more scholars and we got fixed number of chapters and shlokas in most of the edition but there are different recensions of many scriptures and Uddhava Gita is not an exception here.

Same is pointed out by another user [Swami Vishwananda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/882/swami-vishwananda) in his above [comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/41293/why-uddhava-gitas-start-differently-are-there-different-uddhava-gitas#comment129764_41293) "there are different recensions of many shastras, including the Uddhava Gita.".

Now, let's see the differences in the links mentioned by you in the question.

---

The [first link](http://bhagavata.org/pdf/uddhavagita-eng.pdf) [*pdf file might get auto downloaded on clicking this*]

- starts with: [Bhagavata Purana: Canto/Section/Skandha 11: Chapter 6: Shloka 1](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/6/1/)
- total chapters: 24
- chapters included: chapter 6 to 29 of Bhagavata Purana: Canto/Section/Skandha 11

---

The [second link](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/uddhavagiitaa.pdf) [*pdf file might get auto downloaded on clicking this*]

- starts with [Bhagavata Purana: Canto/Section/Skandha 11: Chapter 1: Shloka 1](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/1/1/)
- total chapters: 31
- chapters included: all (1 to 31) chapters of Bhagavata Purana: Canto/Section/Skandha 11

So this link treats whole Canto/Section/Skandha 11 of Bhagavata Purana as Uddhava Gita. This can be observed from the last page also:

> [image]

---

The [third link](https://www.amazon.in/Uddhava-Gita-Krishnas-Final-Lessons-ebook/dp/B00CPG20LO/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=uddhava%20gita&qid=1595865329&sr=8-2#reader_B00CPG20LO)

- starts with [Bhagavata Purana: Canto/Section/Skandha 11: Chapter 7: Shloka 1](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/7/1/)
- total chapters: 23
- chapters included: chapter 7 to 29 of Bhagavata Purana: Canto/Section/Skandha 11

---

**Conclusion**

By reading any of the version, you can get main part of Uddhaava Gita.

But if you want to understand more background, read whole Canto/Section/Skandha 11 of Bhagavata Purana.

Comment: do you recommend to first learn bhagwad mahapuran and then uddhava gita, or the order is not important?

Comment: if u learn bhagwad mahapuran, uddhava gita would be covered automatically as uddhava gita is part of bhagwad mahapuran...but in case u have got less time read only 11th section of bhagwad mahapuran that would also cover uddhava gita..if u hv even lesser time then u can ignore 5 starting and 2 ending chapters of 11th section of bhagwad mahapuran...